# Can not produce angular 6 timestamp, missing imports

Tags: firebase, time, timestamp, angular6

I am trying to produce a timestamp on click (of a button) and another timestamp on click of another button. Essentially a punch clock. I understand how to create the buttons, but have no clue with packages to import that would produce the timestamp ....yes, I've search the entire web for this.

Ultimately I'd like to register that to firebase db for a each registered user, but we'll get to that later.

Comment: Can you include what exactly you have tried so far and what you are having troubles with?

Comment: in html: 
  <button (click)="timein()">
      time in
    </button>

  <button (click)="timeout()">
      time out
    </button>

in ts. file 
  timein(//GET THE TIME//) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .timestamp(//actual time//)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Nice, it worked!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
      });
  }

same for logout. And ideally the is the actuall time display in the HTML

Comment: Can you [edit] that information in your question? And maybe include a sample of your database structure showing where you are trying to save it and the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

user.createdAt = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
user.updatedAt = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

From the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp

Comment: if that were the way to go, user is not found... hmmm

`code  user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

    punchin() {
        this.user.createdAt = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
       }

       punchout() {
        this.user.updatedAt = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
       }`

Comment: @SabrinaTesla well this is another problem. You cannot assign additional properties to the auth user object, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users